# Why does this function not converge in measure?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

### Definition

Let $f$ and $\{f_k\}$ be measurable functions which are defined and finite almost everywhere in a set $E$. Then $\{f_k\}$ is said to *converge in measure* on $E$ to $f$ if for every $\varepsilon\gt0$,
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}
\left|\left\{
\mathbf{x} \in E : \left| f\left(\mathbf{x}\right) - f_k\left(\mathbf{x}\right) \right|\gt \varepsilon
\right\}\right| = 0 $$

---

Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $f_k=1_{\{\mathbf{x]:|\mathbf{x}|\lt k}\}}$, and let $f=1$.

---

I agree that $\{f_k\}$ converges pointwise on $E$ to $f$, since $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k(\mathbf{x}) = 1 =f(\mathbf{x})$.

However, I do not understand why $\{f_k\}$ does not converges in measure on $E$ to $f$. Can someone let me know the reason why it doesn't converge?

Comment: What's the measure of the set $\{ x: \lvert f(x) - f_k(x)\rvert > 1/2\}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Are there many measures? I know only Lebesgue measure. This is also Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I mean the number, how "large" the set is. $\lvert \{ x : \lvert f(x) - f_k(x)\rvert > 1/2\}\rvert$ in your notation.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. How large??

Comment: What is $\lvert \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \lvert f(x) - f_k(x)\rvert > 1/2\}\rvert$? For $k = 1$, for $k = 23$, for $k = 10^{200000}$, for an arbitrary $k$? [Assuming $n = 1$ and $E = \mathbb{R}$ for simplicity.] Note that whether the sequence converges in measure or not depends on $E$.

Comment: @DanielFischer $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is just a sequence of functions. And in the definition, $k$ goes to $\infty$. That is the definition of the textbook. I input one more sentence in my post.

Comment: You don't understand me. Let $F_k := \{ x : \lvert f(x) - f_k(x)\rvert > 1/2\}$. Then which element of $[0,+\infty]$ is $\lvert F_k\rvert$?

Comment: For example, let $f(x)$ be $1$ for $x\ge0$ and $0$ for $x\lt0$. Also, let $f_k(x)$be $1$ for $x\ge\frac1k$ and $0$ for $x\lt\frac1k$. Then, $|F_k|$ is $\frac1k$.

Comment: You have a concrete sequence of functions (and a limit function) given in the question. Use that sequence, don't cook up a new one.